# STI and nested attribute mass assignment in mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, nested-attributes, single-table-inheritance, mass-assignment

Question on mass assignment through nested attributes using mongoid.

Example:

```
require 'mongoid'
require 'mongo'

class Company
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :workers,as: :workable, autosave: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :workers
end

class Worker
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :hours, type: Integer, default: 0
  belongs_to :workable, polymorphic: true
end

class Manager < Worker
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :order
  #attr_accessible :order
  attr_accessor :order

  validates_presence_of :order
end

Mongoid.configure do |config|
  config.master = Mongo::Connection.new.db("mydb")
end
connection = Mongo::Connection.new
connection.drop_database("mydb")
database = connection.db("mydb")

params = {"company" => {"workers_attributes" => {"0" => {"_type" => "Manager","hours" => 50, "order" => "fishing"}}}}
company = Company.create!(params["company"])
company.workers.each do |worker|
  puts "worker = #{worker.attributes}"
end
```

This outputs the following:

```
worker = {"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('4e8c126b1d41c85333000002'), "hours"=>50, "_type"=>"Manager", "workable_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('4e8c126b1d41c85333000001'), "workable_type"=>"Company"}
```

If the commented out line

```
attr_accessible :order
```

is commented in I instead get the following:

```
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: _type, hours
worker = {"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('4e8c12c41d41c85352000002'), "hours"=>0, "_type"=>"Manager", "workable_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('4e8c12c41d41c85352000001'), "workable_type"=>"Company"}
```

Notice how the hours value is not updated from the default.

Question, why does commenting in attr_accessible mess up my document's persistence.  Also I am new to rails and I do not fully understand attr_accessible but I know I need it to fill in fields through my view.  How can I get my document to persist using the attr_accessible line commented in?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all check the API docs for your explanation on `attr_accessible` [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html). That should provide you with a more thorough understanding.

Secondly, you are using `attr_accessor` for order which you do not need because it is a database field.

Lastly, you need to set `attr_accessible :workers_attributes` on your company model. This allows the `:workers_attributes` hash that is created by the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to be persisted through mass assignment.

Comment: That totally works, thanks so much had this problem for a while and wasn't sure where to look till now.

Comment: No worries. I always try to add the associated API docs when answering questions. They are always a great place to look for information.